# Share a queue between processes and threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I'm writing a program (python 2.7) that uses both multiprocessing and multithreading,the multiprocessing is done using Celery library.
I have a function that have to be parallelized using multithreading,so i've implemented a shared "input" queue that stores the arguments for the thread pool (using the python multiprocessing.Manger Queue) and also for each process Ive made "response" queue, the threads stores the computation result in a specific "response queue" according the source process from which the job came from. The problem is that storing the results in the response queues causing memory leak, even though that the results are almost immediately pop out of the queue the memory used by the interpreter keeps rising (used the memory-profiler library to discover) so i suspect that this open issue might be the cause:
https://bugs.python.org/issue33081
My question is what alternatives I could use to replace those python multiprocessing.Manager queues, Ive considered using Pathos multiprocess.Manager queues and pipes (pipes suit me well because there is one publisher and one consumer) but are there any other options i could try without refactoring the code ?
Thank you !